# How to add Rhino Javascript 1.7 library to classpath in Weblogic 10

Tags: java, javascript, weblogic, server-side, rhino

Weblogic packages rhino classes inside weblogic.jar.

I need newer version of rhino js.jar.

If I just distribute the newer rhino js jar like any other third party jar, it does not get loaded, because the older classes inside weblogic.jar are loaded first.

How can I load classes from my custom js.jar in weblogic 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be easy with weblogic-application.xml, just add configuration in following form:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
   <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name>
   <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

It looks like for at least Weblogic 12c that the above format doesn't work. You have to leave out the `.*`'s like so:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
   <package-name>org.apache.log4j</package-name>
   <package-name>antlr</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

A 12c example can be seen in the [Weblogic 12c documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP571).

Answer (score 1):

You also change CLASSPATH(startWebLogic), PRE_CLASSPATH(setDomainEnv) in server start batchs to make your custom class to be used instead WLogic's.

Comment: I this is for SOA instead of web app you can rename the jar to user-patch.jar and copy to product/fmwsoa/Oracle_SOA1/soa/modules.   That jar is in the class path before everything else.  If you already have something inside that jar you can add rhino package to it but by default oracle soa suite installs an empty jar at that location.